# Turning off requirejs promise

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Using require JS.
Can I turn off require promise?
Here is my code (in require module):

```
func1: function () {
    var _this = this;
    require(["psMapa"], function (psMapa) {
        for (var dzien in psMapa.punkty_wycieczki) {
            var m = psMapa.punkty_wycieczki[dzien];
            _this.func2(m);
            psMapa.func3();
        },
    });
},
func2: function (punkt) {
    require(["psMapa"], function (psMapa) {
        consolge.log('triggered after func3');
    });
});
```

In my module I use `func1`. In it I use `require` to load the `psMapa` module (don't want to add a dependency on the whole module because I don't need it always).
Then loop with a `func2` that uses the `psMapa` function (so I have to use require psMapa once more).

The problem is that `require` in `func2` is a promise and isn't linear and that's why `func2` is calculated after `psMapa.func3()` in `func1`.

Can I make `require` work in a linear way?

Comment: call func3 from the require callback in func2

Comment: Can not - this is a sample code.

Comment: ok, then add a callback to func2 and call func3 from that.

Comment: As it is written right now, this question is unclear. It is unclear why "Can not - this is a sample code" somehow precludes the solution presented in the 1st comment but allows the solution presented in the accepted answer. If the fact that "this is a sample code" precludes the solution in the first comment, I don't see how making `func2` require a reference to `psMapa` as its first argument is somehow okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the `psMapa` function to the `func2` after having it loaded in `func1`:

```
func1: function () {
    var _this = this;
    require(["psMapa"], function (psMapa) {
        for (var dzien in psMapa.punkty_wycieczki) {
            var m = psMapa.punkty_wycieczki[dzien];
            _this.func2(psMapa, m);
            psMapa.func3();
        },
    });
},
func2: function (psMapa, punkt) {
    consolge.log('triggered after func3');
}
```